# Paypal activity crashes

Tags: android, button, android-activity, paypal, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to open an `Activity` which includes Paypal button, but it crashes for some reason.

Here's my code for showing the Paypal button and opening the Paypal activity (OnActivityResult is not shown here, Its not important right now.):

```
PayPal ppObj = PayPal.initWithAppID(this.getBaseContext(), "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
```

Inside OnCreate:

```
LinearLayout mLinLay= new LinearLayout(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
LinearLayout layoutSimplePayment = new LinearLayout(this);
        layoutSimplePayment.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layoutSimplePayment.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        CheckoutButton launchSimplePayment = ppObj.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

        launchSimplePayment.setOnClickListener(this);   
        layoutSimplePayment.addView(launchSimplePayment);
        mLinLay.addView(layoutSimplePayment);

        setContentView(mLinLay);
```

OnClick:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();
        payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("10.00"));
        payment.setCurrencyType("USD");
        payment.setRecipient("mymail@gmail.com");
        payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
        payment.setMerchantName("Company");
        Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, this);
        startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
    }
```

LOGCAT:

```
09-10 12:14:07.746: W/dalvikvm(27898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f0a930)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.free/com.example.free.Add}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal.getDensity(Unknown Source)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.paypal.android.MEP.CheckoutButton.a(Unknown Source)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal.getCheckoutButton(Unknown Source)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.example.free.Add.onCreate(Add.java:167)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
09-10 12:14:07.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    ... 11 more
```

What's the problem here?

Thanks!

**Edit**

Thats what I changed:
I still get A Null Pointer exeption...

```
CheckoutButton launchSimplePayment = null;
        if (!(ppObj==null))
        launchSimplePayment = ppObj.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

        if (!(launchSimplePayment==null)){
        launchSimplePayment.setOnClickListener(this);   
        layoutSimplePayment.addView(launchSimplePayment);
        mLinLay.addView(layoutSimplePayment);


        setContentView(mLinLay);}
```

LOGCAT:

```
09-10 12:52:51.902: W/dalvikvm(3578): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f0a930)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.free/com.example.free.Add}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal.getDensity(Unknown Source)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at com.paypal.android.MEP.CheckoutButton.a(Unknown Source)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal.getCheckoutButton(Unknown Source)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at com.example.free.Add.onCreate(Add.java:169)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
09-10 12:52:51.949: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):     ... 11 more
```

Line 169 is:

```
launchSimplePayment = ppObj.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
```

Comment: prevent the Null Pointer Exception by if( == null ), then debug

Comment: Null Pointer Exception in your case, CheckOutButton initialised succesfully in onCreate()

Comment: you mean if if (!null)? Where should I add it? @twntee

Comment: either way, `if null` show/log error `else` do the work.

Comment: Where should I include the if? Sorry for being a such a noob. edit: oh ok just a min

Comment: just before `Line 167` which is causing `NPE`.

Comment: Oh wait but WHAT should I check if its null? @twntee

Comment: Please, its okay. Everyone is a noob when the begin. No body is perfect.

Comment: I mean, what shouldnt be null? @twntee

Comment: `launchSimplePayment` the CheckOut button ! also what is `line 167` in your code in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @twntee I secured it, But it still throws a null pointer exeption. Ive added the new code In the question^^^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37090/discussion-between-nirpes-and-twntee)